# OnClick Gets triggered multiple times

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have this method:

```
public void questions_makealist() {
    qAdapter = new QandARecyclerViewAdapter(qandas);

    qanda_View.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), qanda_View, new ClickListener() { // en as ons op n boksie druk
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Log.e("Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee","On Clicked");
            QandA c_qanda = qandas.get(position);

            flip_it.setDisplayedChild(6);
            reply_View = findViewById(R.id.replies);

            TextView Question_Q = findViewById(R.id.QuestionC);
            TextView Question_A = findViewById(R.id.asked_byC);

            Question_Q.setText(c_qanda.getQuestion());
            Question_A.setText(c_qanda.getABN());

            QID_Reply = c_qanda.getQID();

            maak_die_lys_vir_replies();

        }
        public void onLongClick(View view,int position) {}
        //moet dit hier sit vir die method
    }));

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager qLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    qanda_View.setLayoutManager(qLayoutManager);
    qanda_View.setAdapter(qAdapter);
    //net vir testing purposes
    //add_item("Ds.Hennie", "40 Dae Reeks: Herstel", 1, 1, "6 Maart 2017");
    qandas.clear();
    qAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getQuestions getq = new getQuestions();
    getq.execute();
}
```

And for some reason the on click gets trigered the amounts of times i already clicked it. For example if this is the third time clicking it will litereally call that on click 3 times.

Please see below the error log that i set up.

```
06-06 17:56:32.584 24779-24779/ng.Wilgespruit.com E/Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee: On Clicked
06-06 17:56:32.592 24779-24779/ng.Wilgespruit.com E/Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee: On Clicked
06-06 17:56:32.593 24779-24779/ng.Wilgespruit.com E/Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee: On Clicked
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `onTouchListener()` is triggered multiple times when a view is touched whereas `onClickListener()` is triggered only once when it is clicked.

If you want to add a `onClickListener()` to every item inside a RecyclerView, you can do that inside the adapter class. There are two ways to do it in adapter class.

- Have onClickListener set in `onBindViewHolder()` as `holder.itemView.setOnCLickListener()`
- Have it set inside the ViewHolder class which would inside your adapter.

After setting an onClickListener, you can also pass the event back to the activity from adapter using interfaces.